# Will turn down a graduate (Master's) program have effect on my application for the same program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, time-off

I have asked a similar question.

[Is it bad to apply for the same Master's degree program in consecutive years?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82098/is-it-bad-to-apply-for-the-same-masters-degree-program-in-consecutive-years)

> If I failed the first year, will it be a negative factor for my
>   application the next year (say if I could been admitted originally,
>   but because I failed the last application the year before so I am not
>   accepted)?

But what if it is the other way around. I turn down the admission to do a gap year thing and reapply the same program the next year. Will my rejection in the first year be bad for my application for the same program the next year?

Comment: You previously asked about deferred admission ( http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82125/is-defer-enrollment-normal-or-acceptable-by-graduate-programs-what-are-the-acce ), and this is exactly the kind of situation that deferred admission is designed to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

In most programs, each application is judged on its merits. That said, however, it is likely that a little note will be appended to your file to state that you were accepted into the program last year and that you rejected the offer. How this note will be judged will depend on the admissions committee, of course. However, unless you can provide reasonable evidence explaining your rejection of the offer of admission, I would imagine that it would count negatively in your favour. I suggest that you provide this reason in the statement of purpose.

@Buzz has commented that your question about deferred admission is pertinent here. If there is no reason for you to reject the offer outright, then a program that offers you the chance to defer acceptance should be the way to go. This is usually the case for students wishing to do a "gap year thing".