# Will once turning down Master's admission impact a PhD application in the same department

Tags: phd, application

I notice there have been some similar questions, like [Will turn down a graduate (Master's) program have effect on my application for the same program?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82139/will-turn-down-a-graduate-masters-program-have-effect-on-my-application-for-t).
But my situation is a little bit different.

I once turned down a Master in statistics admission at University A and accept another Master in applied mathematics at University B.
At that time, I think the Master program at University A focus more on the applied statistics but I want to learn more math and theoretical statistics to prepare for applying for statistics PhD program.
So I accept the applied math master program at University B.

I plan to apply for statistics PhD program at University A this fall.

## Question 1

Will I be put into a less favorable place compared to other applicants because of this?

## Question 2

Should I mention that I once turned down the master's admission?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm hoping that University A will be objective in their decision making and not play favorites. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be highly unlikely that they would disadvantage you, unless you are applying to a truly small and petty department. The small part is really key here: for most departments of any size, you would likely be one among potentially dozens to hundreds of applicants. That they would even remember your name on a later admissions from an MS application would be unlikely, unless they already felt you were someone special (which wouldn't hurt you).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But should I mention that I was once admitted but declined the admission in my personal statement?

Comment: @MasamiNagasawa No, I wouldn't do that.